# How to access the flash and redirect_to from a filter class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a class as a before filter for multiple controllers.  Because the filter must do slightly different things based on which controller is calling it, it seems like I need to use a class as a filter in order to get the controller passed in to filter.

So far, I have something like

```
class ShowFilter
def self.filter(controller)
  c_name = controller.controller_name
  object_id = controller.params[:id]
  case c_name
    when "articles"
      article = Article.find(object_id)
      unless curr_user.can_see?(article)
        controller.redirect_to(:controller => "articles", :action => "index")
      end
    when "images"
      image = Image.find(object_id)
      unless curr_user.can_see?(image)
        controller.redirect_to(:controller => "images", :action => "index")
      end
  end
end
```

This class would be called as a :before_filter on the *show* action in the *articles* and *images* controllers.

My problem is that I get an error saying that 'redirect_to' is a protected method of whatever controller gets passed into the filter.

If I call

```
redirect_to(:controller => "images", :action => "index")
```

instead of

```
controller.redirect_to(:controller => "images", :action => "index")
```

I get an "undefined method 'redirect_to' for ShowFilter:Class" error.

If I define my class as

```
class ShowFilter < ApplicationController
```

I still get an undefined method error.  I am having the exact same issues accessing the flash as well.

Is there a way to redirect inside of a filter class?  Should I be using a different method to filter in order to be able to redirect and access the flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use controller.send(:redirect_to, "your url") to bypass the protected level of the method.

Comment: Thanks, Tanel.  Do you have any good links regarding how controller.send works?  I'm still trying to set the flash, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Look up Object#send in the ruby documentation. It's not rails specific.